# How to make a condition in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to make a condition on firebase, taking value, but I'm not sure how to do it.

I need to do this, if the value is horizontal do this, if you do not do that.

My firebase:

leitura: "horizontal"

```
String emailUsuario = autenticacao.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
    String idUsuario = CustomBase64.codificarBase64( emailUsuario );
    favoritosRef = firebaseRef.child("usuarios").child(idUsuario);
    valueEventListenerLeitor = favoritosRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.child("leitura").getValue() == "horizontal") {
                Log.e("TAG", "=======" + dataSnapshot.child("leitura").getValue());
            } else {
                Log.e("TAG", "=======" + "Vertical");
            }
        }



        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: change == to .equals() i:e dataSnapshot.child("leitura").getValue().equals("horizontal")

Comment: Thanks. I got it.

Comment: @GnanendraKumar You should write an answer with your comment, in order for the OP to accept and upvote it.

Comment: I didn't get it sorry. Could you clarify again.

Comment: post your nodes structure.!

Comment: @GnanendraKumar I meant that since you were the first one to give the solution (but as a comment), you should make a genuine answer because you actually deserve the reputation increase. Just a minor remark...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
valueEventListenerLeitor = favoritosRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.child("leitura").getValue().equals("horizontal")) {
            Log.e("TAG", "=======" + dataSnapshot.child("leitura").getValue());
        } else {
            Log.e("TAG", "=======" + "Vertical");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: You should explain what the problem was and what you did to fix it and why that works instead of just dumping code here.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to compare `String` with `==`, which is wrong. Please try to use `equals()` as so:

```
String emailUsuario = autenticacao.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
    String idUsuario = CustomBase64.codificarBase64( emailUsuario );
    favoritosRef = firebaseRef.child("usuarios").child(idUsuario);
    valueEventListenerLeitor = favoritosRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.child("leitura").equals("horizontal")) {
                Log.e("TAG", "=======" + dataSnapshot.child("leitura").getValue());
            } else {
                Log.e("TAG", "=======" + "Vertical");
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```